# svn log to display the changes of merged files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, version

I have a file foo.sql in my svn repository with absolute path /trunk/foo.sql. A branch BRANCH_1 has been created(say branch creation revision is r10) from trunk and many changes/commits are done in foo.sql(r11, r12, r13) in the branch. Once all the changes are done, the branch has been merged to trunk (r15).

Now if I use `svn log /trunk/foo.sql` it will not show the commits info of file in the branch (which is expected). Instead it will show only 1 revision(r15) which corresponds to the merge, though there are multiple changes happened on the file in branch.

I am wondering if there is a way, I can use `svn log` from trunk to see the modifications(r11, r12, r13) of the files which came into trunk via svn merge.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the `-g` switch to `svn log`, that will also display the merged in commits and when they got merged.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Vampire: the longer alias for `-g` is `--use-merge-history` and (at least in the following svn version)

svn, version 1.14.2 (r1899510)
compiled Apr 13 2022, 14:56:48 on arm-apple-darwin21.3.0

the merged commits did not appear right after the merge. I had to do an `svn update` first. After that `svn log -g` worked as expected.